# Adding this project as a reference would cause a circular dependency

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio-2019

I am developing a winforms application using VS2019 after a long time. I am stuck on the situation illustrated below.

I have two projects, ProjectA and ProjectB. In ProjectA I have a form frmA and in ProjectB I have a form frmB. ProjectA is the startup project and it launches frmA which then calls frmB in ProjectB. Thus I added ProjectB as a reference in ProjectA. Trouble starts when I want to call frmA in ProjectA from ProjectB. How do I achieve this without get a circular dependency error?

```
public partial class frmA : Form
{
    public frmA()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void btnA_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ProjectB.frmB form  = new ProjectB.frmB();
        form.Show();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Why not create a ProjectC, in which you add a reference to ProjectA and ProjectB?

Comment: That would mean I can access ProjectA and B and not a form in ProjectC

Comment: @AlexF thanks for your response. May you please clarify your answer with code snippets. I am lost

Comment: @MutongiGava - In what way do you need to access `frmA` from `frmB`? What you want to do will make all of the difference to what solution makes sense.

Comment: @Enigmativity Pretty much the same way as illustrated by my code snippet. frmA is a menu which takes me to frmB. When I am done in frmB, I need to return to the menu which is frmA

Comment: @MutongiGava - You don't need a reference to `frmA` to make that work. You just need a reference to either `Form` or `Func<Form>`.

Comment: Not working either

Comment: @MutongiGava - What's "Not working either"?